# Converting datetime to time in C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, time

I am trying to insert time on my asp.net project.

```
RequestUpdateEmployeeDTR requestUpdateEmployeeDTR = new RequestUpdateEmployeeDTR();
requestUpdateEmployeeDTR.AttendanceDeducID = int.Parse(txtAttendanceDeducID.Text);
requestUpdateEmployeeDTR.TimeInChange = txtTimeOutChange.Text;
requestUpdateEmployeeDTR.TimeOutChange = txtTimeOutChange.Text;
```

`TimeInChange` and `TimeOutChange` are `DateTime` data types. But I am inserting a time data type. How can I convert that into a time data type using C#? Thanks!

Comment: Use `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.ParseExact()`.

Comment: I assume that you have a `Time` column in your DB?

Comment: you can try use `TimeOfDay`property, or use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework does not have a native `Time` data type to represent a time of day.  You will have to decide between one of the three following options:

#### Option 1

Use a `DateTime` type, and ignore the date portion.  Pick a date that's outside of a normal range of values for your application.  I typically use `0001-01-01`, which is conveniently available as `DateTime.MinValue`.

If you are parsing a time from a string, the easiest way to do this is with the `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` option.  Without this option, it would use *today's* date instead of the min date.

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Parse("12:34", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                          DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

// Result:  0001-01-01 12:34:00
```

Of course, if you prefer to use *today's* date, you can do that.  I just think it confuses the issue because you might be looking to apply this to some other date entirely.

Note that once you have a `DateTime` value, you can use the `.TimeOfDay` property to get at just the time portion, represented as a `TimeSpan`, which leads to option 2...

#### Option 2

Use a `TimeSpan` type, but be careful in how you interpret it.  Understand that `TimeSpan` is first and foremost a type for representing an *elapsed duration of time*, not a time of day.  That means it can store more than 24 hours, and it can also store *negative* values to represent moving backwards in time.

When you use it as a time of day, you might be inclined to think of it as "elapsed time since midnight".  This, however, will get you into trouble because there are days where midnight *does not exist* in the local time zone.

For example, [October 20th 2013 in Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=233&year=2013) started at 1:00 AM due to daylight saving time.  So a `TimeSpan` of `8:00` on this day would actually have been only 7 hours elapsed since 1:00, not 8 hours elapsed since midnight.

Even in the United States, for locations that use daylight saving time, this value is misleading.  For example, [November 3rd 2013 in Los Angeles](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=137&year=2013) had a duplicated hour for when DST rolled back.  So a `TimeSpan` of `8:00` on this day would actually had **9 hours** elapsed since midnight.

So if you use this option, just be careful to treat it as the representative time value that matches a clock, and not as "time elapsed since midnight".

You can get it directly from a string with the following code:

```
TimeSpan myTime = TimeSpan.Parse("12:34", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

#### Option 3

Use a library that has a true "time of day" type.  You'll find this in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/), which offers a *much* better API for working with date and time in .NET.

The type that represents a "time of day" is called `LocalTime`, and you can get one from a string like this:

```
var pattern = LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("HH:mm");
LocalTime myTime = pattern.Parse("12:34").Value;
```

Since it appears from your question that you are working with [time and attendance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/time-and-attendance/info) data, I strongly suggest you use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) for all your date and time needs.  It will force you to put more thought into what you are doing.  In the process, you will avoid the pitfalls that can come about with the built-in date/time types.

If you are storing a `Time` type in your database (such as SQL server), that gets translated as a `TimeSpan` in .Net. So if you go with this option, you'll need to convert the `LocalTime` to a `TimeSpan` as follows:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(myTime.TickOfDay);
```